# Too many query rows: 1000001 - Is this a new undocumented limit?

Tags: apex, governorlimits

A page that yesterday generated a timeout today showed this new error

> Too many query rows: 1000001 Error is in expression '{!myMethod}' in
>   page myPage

I know this error with ten thousand records from [Understanding Execution Governors and Limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) but with a million records?!

Have you ever seen this? Or this a new limit introduced by Summer '13.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like you're hitting the query row limit on a visualforce page declared with readonly. Per the [visualforce documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm):

> Normally, queries for a single Visualforce page request may not
>   retrieve more than 50,000 rows. In read-only mode, this limit is
>   relaxed to allow querying up to 1 million rows.

Comment: Ah you're right, that does like the message.

Comment: The limits documentation for readonly is well hidden and sometimes undocumented, very hard to find. For example a ReadOnly RemoteAction method can retrieve 100k rows! Numbers are all over the place based on context.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [selectivity](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm), the initial threshold is 1,000,000 rows

> The selectivity threshold is 10% of the records for the first million
>   records and less than 5% of the records after the first million
>   records, up to a maximum of 333,000 records. In some circumstances,
>   for example with a query filter that is an indexed standard field, the
>   threshold may be higher. Also, the selectivity threshold is subject to
>   change.
>
> A query is selective when one of the query filters is on an indexed
>   field and the query filter reduces the resulting number of rows below
>   a system-defined threshold. The performance of the SOQL query improves
>   when two or more filters used in the WHERE clause meet the mentioned
>   conditions.

Comment: Selectivity only is required in triggers (pages and webservices can run non-selective queries, but they must complete before the timout) and has a different error message.